# Download OpenCL headers

Tags: sdk, opencl, nvidia

Where can I download OpenCL v1.1 headers ? I'm trying to compile a project that require it, the headers are

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <CL/cl_ext.h>
```

I tried installing https://developer.nvidia.com/content/cuda-toolkit-11-june- but I can't find the headers.

Comment: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/

Answer (score 0):

You can download it here: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.1/

I don't think CUDA toolkit has OpenCL headers